# How to ignore bad characters in a SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, character

The short story is I have a SQL Server DB with varchar fields instead of datetime (don't ask, it's a long story and can't be fixed). Somehow we've recently been getting weird / random characters inserted in these fields instead of what should be there (either NULL, '' or YYYY-MM-DD). Something like this: '?+x' with high-bit ascii characters.

The report uses this query to help massage the data into something usable (only relevant parts posted here):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN c.CallStatus = 'Closed' THEN CAST(c.ClosedDate + ' ' + c.ClosedTime as datetime) ELSE NULL END as 'Closed Date'
WHERE CAST(c.closeddate AS DATETIME) BETWEEN  @StartDate AND @EndDate
```

but it is choking on this new bad data.

### My question is this:

How can I update the query to ignore the bad data so I can get the reports to run while I hunt down the source of the bad data? My first priority is to get the reports to function, second is to find and kill the source of bad data.

Comment: The point of a transactional database is to enforce data integrity.  If you've already got bad data in there, you're pretty much hosed.

Comment: @Aaronaught - you are only half right, prevention is always better than cure, and such data should never be allowed in. But dealing with this kind of thing is, sadly, a fundamental part of working in most teams!!

Comment: I would be very, very worried if I found binary junk in my database. Is table corruption not a possibility here?

Comment: it's not a transactional DB (crap vendor platform and we can't change it). don't think it's corruption as junk is limited to date / time fields (which are varchars and can't be changed) for new entries only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
CASE WHEN ISDATE(closeddate) = 1 THEN CAST(c.closeddate AS DATETIME) ELSE NULL END
```

Comment: I was going to post with ISDATE() in the WHERE clause. Either works.

Comment: Thanks, the original post was part of the WHERE clause (updated to be clearer). How would I update the WHERE clause (I think that's where it's failing)?

Answer (score 0):

Looks to be all fixed, thankyouverymuch! here's my final result:

> AND case WHEN ISDATE (closeddate) = 1
>   THEN CAST(c.closeddate AS DATETIME) 
>   ELSE NULL END BETWEEN  @StartDate AND
>   @EndDate

and now on to the hunt!